# Polars python: interpolation in the groupby context

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars, lazyframe

In polars python I have a datafame with 3 columns `x`: integers (mod 5 continuous integers with missing values), `y`: integers and `z`: str (category).
I want to group by the column z and interpolate column x and y. Here is an example dataframe:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 5   ┆ 1   ┆ A   │
│ 10  ┆ 2   ┆ A   │
│ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ A   │
│ 25  ┆ 5   ┆ A   │
│ 10  ┆ 2   ┆ B   │
│ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ B   │
│ 30  ┆ 6   ┆ B   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

And here is the desired output:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 5   ┆ 1   ┆ A   │
│ 10  ┆ 2   ┆ A   │
│ 15  ┆ 3   ┆ A   │
│ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ A   │
│ 25  ┆ 5   ┆ A   │
│ 10  ┆ 2   ┆ B   │
│ 15  ┆ 3   ┆ B   │
│ 20  ┆ 4   ┆ B   │
│ 25  ┆ 5   ┆ B   │
│ 30  ┆ 6   ┆ B   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

the steps between each x values (for each category) should be always 5. My real dataframe is very large so I wish I can work with `pl.LazyFrame` instead of `pl.DataFrame`

Without the category column `z` I solved the issue with a join:

```py
import polars as pl

#  Main dataframe
data = dict(x=[10, 20, 30], y=[2, 4, 6])
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Dataframe with all x values
step = 5 
df_1 = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=range(df["x"].min(), df["x"].max() + step, step)))

#  merging and interpolation 
print((
    df_1
    .join(df, on="x", how="left")
    .with_columns(pl.col("y").interpolate())
))
```

and the result was:

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 10  ┆ 2   │
│ 15  ┆ 3   │
│ 20  ┆ 4   │
│ 25  ┆ 5   │
│ 30  ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

This works as expected, but I can not figure out how to apply this in the group_by context

Comment: Is there a typo in the desired output, i.e.  should the `3` in the line `25 | 3 | B` be a `5` instead?

Comment: yas sorry this is a typo, the correct value is `25 | 5 | B`

Comment: Hmm.. Usually, I'd look at [`pl.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic.html). However, unlike pandas, polars doesn’t add extra rows for empty windows. For this, you'd need [`pl.DataFrame.upsample`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.upsample.html), which currently only supports upsampling of time columns.

Comment: In general, performing joins in polars is very efficient. However, I am still contemplating about the best way to create the upsampled dataframe.

Comment: upsampling with `pl.DataFrame.upsample` may work because In my real dataset I have timestamps for the column `x` I used integers in my example to make it a more general case. however the `upsample` method do not exists for `pl.LazyFrame` and my dataset is very large so I would prefer a `pl.LazyFrame`

Comment: upsample just creates a range and does a join: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12207#issuecomment-1793059330

Comment: @jqurious I did not know that - thanks! In this case, my answer is a manual implementation of `upsample` for integer columns...

Answer (score 3):

You could extend your example based on [`pl.DataFrame.join`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html) by joining on `x` and `z` as follows.

First, we create an upsampled DataFrame (for all groups defined by `z`) to join on.

```py
upsampled = (
    df
    .group_by("z")
    .agg(
        pl.int_range(pl.col("x").min(), pl.col("x").max()+5, step=5).alias("x")
    )
    .explode("x")
)
```

Next, we perform a left-join on the upsampled DataFrame and interpolate column `y`.

```py
(
    upsampled
    .join(
        df,
        on=["x", "z"],
        how="left"
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("y").interpolate()
    )
)
```

**Output** (ordering may differ when not setting `maintain_order=True` in the `group_by`) **.**

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ z   ┆ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 5   ┆ 1.0 │
│ A   ┆ 10  ┆ 2.0 │
│ A   ┆ 15  ┆ 3.0 │
│ A   ┆ 20  ┆ 4.0 │
│ A   ┆ 25  ┆ 5.0 │
│ B   ┆ 10  ┆ 2.0 │
│ B   ┆ 15  ┆ 3.0 │
│ B   ┆ 20  ┆ 4.0 │
│ B   ┆ 25  ┆ 5.0 │
│ B   ┆ 30  ┆ 6.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: And this is even working with lazy frames! thank you very much :-)